# Does Helm also remove the created namespace if `helm install` fails and --atomic option has been used

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Does Helm also remove the created namespace if `helm install` fails and `--atomic` option has been used to install the release?

I am unable to find this information on Helm help pages.

Answer (score 1):

The namespace is not deleted.

In the Helm source, [`"helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action".Install`](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/f31d4fb3aacabf6102b3ec9214b3433a3dbf1812/pkg/action/install.go) has the main logic that `helm install` actually runs.  The `--atomic` handling more specifically is in [`(*Install).failRelease()`](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/f31d4fb3aacabf6102b3ec9214b3433a3dbf1812/pkg/action/install.go#L467-L482), which is approximately

```golang
rel.SetStatus(release.StatusFailed, fmt.Sprintf("Release %q failed: %s", i.ReleaseName, err.Error()))
if i.Atomic {
    uninstall := NewUninstall(i.cfg)
    ... uninstall.Run(i.ReleaseName) ...
}
i.recordRelease(rel)
```

The very last line is important here.  This calls through to [`(*"helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/storage".Storage).Update()`](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/f31d4fb3aacabf6102b3ec9214b3433a3dbf1812/pkg/storage/storage.go#L75), which records the fact of the failed release where `helm history` can find it.  With the normal Helm configuration, this is in a Secret in the target namespace.  Since the history is recorded in a Secret in the namespace, the namespace can't be deleted.

It's easy to search the source for the `Atomic` setting, and at least in `install.go` the only two things it does are to implicitly enable `--wait` and to run `helm uninstall` if the install fails.  But neither of those things delete the namespace.